# increment count when button is clicked C# Visual Studio 2013

Tags: c#, asp.net

So, i am trying to increment a count every time i click a button. And as for the count, i want to save it into an arraylist, after that, i want to retrieve the database by using the last row of arraylist as the ID

```
public partial class Queue : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    ArrayList array = new ArrayList();
    int count = 0;

    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        LblDate.Text = DateTime.Today.ToString("dd-MM-yyyy");
        array.Add(count);
    }

    protected void Timer1_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        LblTime.Text = DateTime.Now.ToString("HH:mm:ss");
    }

    protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {  
        count++;
        array.Add(count);
        int last = Convert.ToInt32(array[array.Count - 1]);

        queue fmCustomer = new queue();
        fmCustomer = fmCustomer.getQueueNoByID(last.ToString());

        Label1.Text = last.ToString();
    }
}
```

These are my codes, the problem i am facing now is i can only increment once for the count.

When i click the button, it display 1, but after that it wont increase again

So i would need some help with that.

Comment: put  count++ outside of if(button1WasClicked == true) condition.

Comment: If you just want to get the last inserted row then there is no need to increment a variable and get the last record. You just need to modify your query by just "Select Max(Column_Name) from Table"

Comment: i tried putting the count++ outside and it doesnt work.

Is there a way to add a value into a database whenever the button is clicked? Cause i am trying to build a Queue System, whereby i click and button and a number will be displayed, of course the number will be increased each time it is clicked

Answer (score 0):

I see a few issues with the code..

1. Why is count set to 1 and not 0?
2. What is the purpose of button1WasClicked
3. What do you plan to do with this array list - even if your code was working it would just be a list of 0,1,2 ... N where N = number of clicks

Comment: Where in the code is button1WasClicked set to true?

Comment: Hi thank you for replying

I changed the count to 0 already, that was my mistake

As for the button1wasclicked, i saw it online, and tried to add it in

Basically, what i am trying to do is, something like a Queue System, where customer click on the button, and they will get a Queue Number, so by clicking the button i am trying to retrieve a value from database.

And yap, my coding is really really bad, please pardon me

Comment: Hi i add updated it. But as i said i am a novice, so the coding will be terrible

Comment: @Ben this is not an answer, but a comment.

Comment: Actually they were rhetorical answers which helped the OP see his mistakes

Answer (score 0):

Button1_Click event will be fired when you click the button. 
You don't need to check button1WasClicked == true

Answer (score 0):

You are using a Page class. This class will be destroyed after your request response. If will be recreated for the next request.

Therefore button1WasClicked will always be false, and array will always be initialized (and therefore empty).

The Page_Load event will always fire on every request. This will cause your array to always get the value 1.

You need to step back and take some time to understand the page lifecycle for aspx. Also you can set brakepoints and inspect what your code is doing.

Comment: Thank you for replying, but yes i am really confused.

I am suppose to create  a Queue System, so i am not sure what i am doing is correct or not.